# Understand `openssl speed`

Tags: performance, openssl, rsa

I ran `openssl speed rsa512` and it shows me how many signs and verifies it can do in a second. Unfortunalely, the test does not say anything about the message size, which is signed. Thus I digged into the openssl sources and found the following line in the [`speed.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/speed.c#L955):

```
ret = RSA_sign(NID_md5_sha1, buf, 36, buf2, rsa_num, rsa_key[testnum]);
```

Looking into the function in the [`rsa.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/rsa.h#L305), I can see the following function declaration:

```
int RSA_sign(int type, const unsigned char *m, unsigned int m_length,
             unsigned char *sigret, unsigned int *siglen, RSA *rsa);
```

I guess, `m` is the message and `m_length` is the length of the message.

> Am I right that the message size is 36 byte in the RSA speed test?

The same goes for ECDSA, e.g., `openssl speed ecdsap256`. The [`speed.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/speed.c#L1042) uses the following line:

```
ret = ECDSA_sign(0, buf, 20, ecdsasig, ecdsasiglen, ecdsa[testnum]);
```

> Am I right that the message size is 20 byte in the ECDSA speed test?

**My Conclusion**: It's not possible to compare them, since they sign different message lengths.

Answer (score 4):

Asymmetric signatures, technically, don't sign messages.  They sign hashes of messages.

Their rsa512 test is doing the RSA signature padding and transformation on an SSL "MD5 and SHA1" value (which is 16 + 20 = 36 bytes).  So the number it produces is how many RSA pad-and-sign (and answer-copy) operations it can do, you need to divide that by the time it takes to hash the message.

Their ecdsap256 computation is assuming that the digest was SHA-1 (20 bytes).  Again, you would take this number divided by the time it takes to hash a message.

Since they both are in scale terms of the data hashing they're comparable.